# Solving the Schrodinger equation for a particle moving in a central potential

Tags: quantum-mechanics, homework-and-exercises, wavefunction, potential, schroedinger-equation

I have derived the following relation for a particle with angular quantum number $ℓ=0$ in a given potential. I know this to be correct.
$$R(r)=\sqrt{\frac{2}{a}}\frac{\sin{\left(\frac{n\pi r}{a}\right)}}{r},$$
This is the radial part of the wave function relation:
$$\Phi=R(r)Y_{ℓm}(\theta,\phi),$$
I understand the general expression of $Y_{ℓm}$ to be:
$$Y_{ℓm}=\left(-1\right)^m i^ℓ \sqrt{\frac{2(ℓ+1)}{4\pi} \frac{\left(ℓ-|m|\right)!}{\left(ℓ+|m|\right)!}} P_ℓ^{|m|} cos{\theta} e^{im\phi},$$
Hence in the case where $ℓ=0$, as $|m|\leq ℓ$ $m=0$, hence most of these terms go to one, hence we get:
$$Y_{ℓm}=\sqrt{\frac{1}{2\pi}} \cos{\theta},$$
This would then give:
$$\Phi=\sqrt{\frac{1}{2\pi}}\sqrt{\frac{2}{a}}\frac{\sin{\left(\frac{n\pi r}{a}\right)}}{r} \cos{\theta},$$

My problem comes with the simplification of $Y_{ℓm}$, If someone could explain to me what each of the terms in $Y_{ℓm},$ means.

Comment: The expression for the spherical harmonics has $P_l^m(\cos(\theta))$ not $P_l^m \times \cos(\theta)$

Comment: You have only the $Y_{00} = 1/\sqrt{4 \pi}$ component, which is not what you chose

Comment: Also, the normalization on $Y_0^0$ is $\sqrt{\frac{1}{4\pi}}$, not $\sqrt{\frac{1}{2\pi}}$.

Comment: This confusion to me suggests you don't understand where the spherical harmonics come from.  The usual pedagogic route to them first goes via Legendre polynomials $P_l$ as found for example in the solution to Laplace's equation with azimuthal symmetry, or in the multipole expansion of the Coulomb potential. Once you understand that, then you can go into the associated Legendre polynomials $P_l^m$.

Comment: May be a stupid question, but what is $P_{ℓ}^m$ ?

Comment: A detailed explanation is on [Wikipedia's page on Spherical Harmonics](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Spherical_harmonics)

Comment: It's not a stupid question, but the essence of your confusion. The associated Legendre polynomials are polynomials in powers of $cos(\theta)$

Comment: Ok, so for an Angular momentum quantum number of zero, the associated Legendre polynomial is simply 1 right, so I am still out by a factor of $\frac{1}{\sqrt{2}}$ ?

Comment: Please note that [homework-like questions](https://physics.meta.stackexchange.com/q/714/50583) and [check-my-work questions](https://physics.meta.stackexchange.com/q/6093/50583) are generally considered off-topic here. We intend our questions to be potentially useful to a broader set of users than just the one asking, and prefer *conceptual* questions over those just asking for a specific computation.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

The correct expression for spherical harmonics in the context of quantum mechanics is
\begin{equation}
Y^{m}_{\ell} (\theta, \varphi) = (-1)^m \sqrt{\frac{(2 \ell + 1)}{4 \pi} \frac{(\ell - m)!}{ (\ell + m)!}} P^m_{\ell} (\cos \theta) e^{i m \varphi}
\end{equation}
with P the Legendre polynomial (they have a number of different expressions, one of the most common definitions is Rodrigues' formula):
\begin{equation}
P_l(x) = \frac{1}{2^l l!} \frac{d^l}{dx^l} \left[(x^2 - 1)^l \right]
\end{equation}

When $l=0$, $\forall x$,

\begin{equation}
P_0 (x) = 1 
\end{equation}

So if you take $\ell=0$, $m=0$ you get
\begin{equation}
Y^0_0 (\theta, \varphi) = 1 \cdot \sqrt{\frac{1}{4 \pi} \cdot 1} \cdot 1 \cdot 1 = \sqrt{\frac{1}{4 \pi}}
\end{equation}
And thus for every $\theta$ and $\varphi$, you have
\begin{equation}
Y^0_0 = \sqrt{\frac{1}{4 \pi}}.
\end{equation}

Hope that helps !

Comment: Maybe I am missing some really simple maths? but surely $\sqrt{\frac{2}{4\pi}}$ simplifies to $\sqrt{\frac{1}{2\pi}}$ as I had before?!

Comment: I realised, I had the formula noted incorrectly, which lead to the extra factor of two within the brackets, thanks

Comment: im so ashamed of myself right now, correcting that ^^